# Кодировка при записи в XML

Tags: java, xml, jsp, dom

Добрый день, записываю данный с jsp формы в XML и столкнулся с проблемой, что русские буквы не хочет XML принимать, получаются кракозябры.

Заголовок XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Везде UTF-8 и при записи `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");`

Пример, слово `пароль` в файлик записал `Ð¿Ð°Ñ&#128;Ð¾Ð»Ñ&#140;`.

Бьюсь уже второй день, никак :(

Может кто подскажет, в чем косяк? jsp тоже все на UTF-8.

Если нужна доп.информация, то я предоставлю

Comment: А просматриваете в какой кодировке?

Comment: У меня все на UTF-8. И вьюхи и XML и даже через nodepad++ сохранял специально в UTF-8. Если руками записать, то все ок, а вот через jsp никак.